# Designing window frames (of real houses) with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, 2d, cad

In my new project with React, I need to implement an environment for designing doors and windows so that the user can design frames through the browser (like the two figures below) and then save it on the server-side. Then I have to fetch and display it in the mobile application that is implemented with React Native. I searched for it but couldn't find anything special that would work. I even found "konvajs" that has done some work in this area but it doesn't work for me and I think I need to develop this feature myself. If you know of any tools or technologies for this, please let me know. If not, what do you think I can do about it?

[picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLfqM.png)
[picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enjSL.png)

Comment: Because the terms "window" and "frame" each have also at least one meaning in software development you might want to change the title to something like "Designing window frames (of real houses) with React".

Comment: I appreciate your help .

Comment: Tip: like questions and answers, you can also upvote comments, to show your appreciation :-). Finally, this reputation-point-based gamification is what many people motivates to put so much effort in this platform.

Comment: Have you gotten answer yet, or could you please share help on this, I have same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525337

Comment: how can we get width and height values and display them along the rectangle? i.e.  dimension of the the frame