# Create frames and get coordinates of drawing in Konva React JS

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I have the following code file `App.js`, using this code I am able to draw square/rectangle shape using mouse events.

[image]

see working here : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/18588785?key=8a5877587128b9d65b77999becd3f2e3

> App.js File code:

```
import store from './store/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import DrawAnnotations from "./components/DrawAnnotations";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <DrawAnnotations />
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

> DrawAnnotations.js File Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
    setMouseDownReading,
    setMouseUpReading,
    measureLength,
    setMouseDownAnnotations,
    setMouseMoveAnnotations,
    setMouseUpAnnotations,
    setAnnotationsToDraw
} from "../store/dataReadingSlice";

import {
    Stage,
    Layer,
    Rect,
    Group,
    Label,
    Text,
    Line,
} from "react-konva";

const DrawAnnotations = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const dataReading = useSelector((state) => state.dataReading);

    const [annotations, setAnnotations] = useState([]);
    const [newAnnotation, setNewAnnotation] = useState([]);

    const handleMouseDown = event => {
        if (newAnnotation.length === 0) {
            const { x, y } = event.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();

            let mouseDownCoords = {
                x: x, y: y
            }
            dispatch(setMouseDownReading(mouseDownCoords))
            dispatch(setMouseDownAnnotations({ x, y, width: 0, height: 0, key: "0" }))
            setNewAnnotation([{ x, y, width: 0, height: 0, key: "0" }]);
        }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = event => {
        if (newAnnotation.length === 1) {
            const sx = newAnnotation[0].x;
            const sy = newAnnotation[0].y;
            const { x, y } = event.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
            let mouseUpCoords = {
                x: x, y: y
            }
            dispatch(setMouseUpReading(mouseUpCoords))

            const annotationToAdd = {
                x: sx,
                y: sy,
                width: x - sx,
                height: y - sy,
                key: annotations.length + 1,
                strokeWidth: 10,
                stroke: '#F75200',
                dashwidth: [0, 0]
            };
            dispatch(setMouseUpAnnotations(annotationToAdd))
            annotations.push(annotationToAdd);
            dispatch(measureLength())
            setNewAnnotation([]);
            setAnnotations(annotations);
            //dispatch(setAnnotationsToDraw(annotationsToDraw))
        }
    };

    const handleMouseMove = event => {
        if (newAnnotation.length === 1) {
            const sx = newAnnotation[0].x;
            const sy = newAnnotation[0].y;
            const { x, y } = event.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
            dispatch(setMouseMoveAnnotations(
                {
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    width: x - sx,
                    height: y - sy,
                    key: "0"
                }
            ))
            setNewAnnotation([
                {
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    width: x - sx,
                    height: y - sy,
                    key: "0"
                }
            ]);
        }
    };

    const handler = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const annotationsToDraw = [...annotations, ...newAnnotation];

    return (
        <Stage
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            width={1200}
            height={1000}
        >
            {dataReading.rectangles.length > 0 &&
                dataReading.rectangles.map((rectangle, rectIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <Layer key={rectIndex}>
                            {
                                rectangle.annotationsData.map((value, index) => {
                                //annotationsToDraw.map((value, index) => {
                                    
                                    return (
                                        <Group key={index}>
                                            {/* Line for X */}
                                            {value.width > 20 &&
                                                <>
                                                    <Line
                                                        points={[0, 0, rectangle.measureXYLength.x, 0]}
                                                        stroke='blue'
                                                        strokeWidth={5}
                                                        lineJoin='round'
                                                        x={value.x}
                                                        y={value.y - 25}
                                                    />
                                                    <Label
                                                        x={(value.x + value.width) / 2}
                                                        y={value.y - 50}
                                                    >
                                                        <Text
                                                            text={rectangle.measureXYLength.x + " px"}
                                                            padding={10}
                                                            height={30}
                                                            width={150}
                                                            verticalAlign="middle"
                                                        />
                                                    </Label>
                                                </> 
                                            }


                                            {/* Rectangle */}
                                            <Rect
                                                x={value.x}
                                                y={value.y}
                                                width={value.width}
                                                height={value.height}
                                                fill="#C5E6ED"
                                                stroke={value.stroke ? value.stroke : 'blue'}
                                                strokeWidth={value.strokeWidth}
                                                dash={value.dashwidth ? value.dashwidth : [5, 5]}
                                                shadowBlur={10}
                                            />

                                            
                                            
                                            {/* Line for Y  */}
                                            {value.height > 20 &&
                                                <>
                                                    <Line
                                                        points={[-20, 0, -20, rectangle.measureXYLength.y]}
                                                        stroke='red'
                                                        strokeWidth={5}
                                                        lineJoin='round'
                                                        x={value.x}
                                                        y={value.y}
                                                    />
            
                                                    <Label
                                                        x={value.x - 75}
                                                        y={(value.y + value.height ) / 2}
                                                    >
                                                        <Text
                                                            text={rectangle.measureXYLength.y + " px"}
                                                            height={30}
                                                            width={100}
                                                            verticalAlign="middle"
                                                        />
                                                    </Label>
                                                </>
                                            }
                                        </Group>
                                    );
                                })
                            }
                        </Layer>
                    )
                })}
        </Stage>
    );
};

export default DrawAnnotations;
```

dataReadingSlice.js file code

```
const { createSlice } = require('@reduxjs/toolkit')

const dataReadingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dataReading',
    initialState: {
        stateCount: {
            index: 0,
        },
        rectangles:[{
                mouseDownReading: {},
                mouseUpReading: {},
                measureXYLength:{x: 0,y: 0},
                annotationsData: []
            }
        ],
        mouseDownReading: {},
        mouseUpReading: {},
        measureXYLength:{x: 0,y: 0},
        annotations: [],
        annotationsToDraw: []
    },
    reducers: {
        setMouseDownReading(state, action) {           
            state.mouseDownReading = action.payload
        },
        setMouseUpReading(state, action) {
            state.mouseUpReading = action.payload
        },
        setMouseDownAnnotations(state, action) {
            state.annotations.push(action.payload)
        },
        setMouseMoveAnnotations(state, action) {
            state.annotations.push(action.payload)
        },
        setMouseUpAnnotations(state, action) {
            state.annotations = []
            state.annotations.push(action.payload)
        },
        measureLength(state, action) {
            let indexCount = state.stateCount.index

            state.rectangles[indexCount] = {
                mouseDownReading: state.mouseDownReading,
                mouseUpReading : state.mouseUpReading,
                measureXYLength:{
                    x: parseFloat(state.mouseUpReading.x) - parseFloat(state.mouseDownReading.x),
                    y: parseFloat(state.mouseUpReading.y) - parseFloat(state.mouseDownReading.y)
                },
                annotationsData: state.annotations
            }
            state.stateCount.index =  state.stateCount.index + 1
        },
        setAnnotationsToDraw(state, action) {
            //console.log("draw method called")
            //console.log(action.payload)
            //state.annotationsToDraw = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { 
    setMouseDownReading,
    setMouseUpReading,
    measureLength,
    setMouseDownAnnotations,
    setMouseMoveAnnotations,
    setMouseUpAnnotations,
    setAnnotationsToDraw
} = dataReadingSlice.actions
export default dataReadingSlice.reducer
```

I have to make the shape as follows:
[image]

How could I display length and width of each side on the center of side? how to set their positioning as per required?

Comment: Well done so far. Your requirement is composed of a number of techniques and understandings and is probably best suited to a number of discussions on the Discord channel. This question will likely get voted to close because of the request for 'how to achieve' rather than being a specific single issue.